# Why does my function self.deleteTime == None?

Tags: python, function, return-value

So as you can see in the code it should return a random number between 2 and 10 but in return None why??

```
                self.deleteTime = self.buttonGrow.is_pressed(mousePos, mousePressed)
                print(self.deleteTime)

class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, image, content, fontsize, actionID):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font('assets/font/font.otf', fontsize)
        self.content = content

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.id = actionID
        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.fg = (82, 82, 82)

        # Load the image and set the button's image surface dimensions
        self.background_image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.background_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.background_image, (self.width, self.height))
        self.rect = self.background_image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self):
        # Draw the button's background image
        self.screen.blit(self.background_image, self.rect)

        # Render the text and center it on the button
        text_render = self.font.render(self.content, True, self.fg)
        text_rect = text_render.get_rect(center=(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery))
        self.screen.blit(text_render, text_rect)

    def is_pressed(self, pos, pressed):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pressed[0] and self.id == 1:
                self.newTime = random.randint(2, 10)
                print(self.newTime)
                return self.newTime
```

I was expecting the result to be a random number between 2 to 10 but it always returns None.

Comment: The `return` statement is under a couple of `if`s. If the conditions aren't met, not `return` is called explicitly, so the function implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Out of topic, but I would expect from a function name like `is_pressed` to return a boolean notifying if the button is pressed or not. Maybe `press` or `pressed` would be a more accurate naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can return None as default return type of method if none of your if statement executed then function returns nothin(None)

if `self.rect.collidepoint(pos)` - false
`self.id`  != 1 or `pressed[0]` - false

```
def is_pressed(self, pos, pressed):
    if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
        if pressed[0] and self.id == 1:
            self.newTime = random.randint(2, 10)
            print(self.newTime)
            return self.newTime
```